# Qobject::connect problema de conexión de argumentos entre hilos

Tags: python, python-3.x, hilos, pyqt5

Estoy trabajando en un código que realiza lo siguiente:

- Realiza una conexión a firebase mediante la paqueteria **firebase_admin** desde ahi obtiene X datos para mostrar en un **QTableWidget**.

Para optimizar el proceso realizo la petición a firebase desde un **QThread**, hasta aqui todo funciona el problema viene al final.

**PROBLEMA:**

Una vez que termina de realizar la petición y debe mostrar la información en el **QTableWidget** obtengo una advertencia como esta:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Ademas de esto, la información no se muestra en la tabla almenos que haga click sobre ella, es decir, a menos que la tabla este en un estado **focus** no muestra la información como se ve a continuación

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Espero puedan ayudarme a resolver ese inconveniente:

**Codigo.py**

```
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QMainWindow,QApplication
from firebase_admin import credentials,db
from PyQt5 import uic
from PyQt5 import QtCore
import firebase_admin

class MyThread(QtCore.QThread):
    finished = QtCore.pyqtSignal(bool)
    def __init__(self,function):
        QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)
        self.function = function

    def run(self):
        self.function()
        self.finished.emit(True)

class Main(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        QMainWindow.__init__(self)
        uic.loadUi("test.ui",self)

        self.Button.clicked.connect(self.master)

    def master(self):
        self.T = MyThread(self.get_firebase)
        self.T.finished.connect(self.func_fin)
        self.T.start()

    def setItems(self,tabla,row,column,text):
        tabla.item(row,column).setText(text)

    def get_firebase(self):

        cred = credentials.Certificate("AuthLogin.json")
        firebase_admin.initialize_app(cred,{
            'databaseURL':'https://exe-tablas.firebaseio.com/'
        })

        ref = db.reference("/sucursales/")
        ret = ref.get()

        for index,key in enumerate(ret.keys()):
            self.setItems(self.Table,index,0,key)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(bool)
    def func_fin(self,emit):
        print(emit)




app = QApplication([])
m = Main()
m.show()
app.exec_()
```

**file.ui**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ui version="4.0">
 <class>MainWindow</class>
 <widget class="QMainWindow" name="MainWindow">
  <property name="geometry">
   <rect>
    <x>0</x>
    <y>0</y>
    <width>874</width>
    <height>543</height>
   </rect>
  </property>
  <property name="windowTitle">
   <string>MainWindow</string>
  </property>
  <widget class="QWidget" name="centralwidget">
   <widget class="QTableWidget" name="Table">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>20</x>
      <y>10</y>
      <width>251</width>
      <height>151</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>one</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>two</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>three</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <row>
     <property name="text">
      <string>four</string>
     </property>
    </row>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>one</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <column>
     <property name="text">
      <string>two</string>
     </property>
    </column>
    <item row="0" column="0">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="0" column="1">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="0">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="1" column="1">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="0">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="2" column="1">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="0">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
    <item row="3" column="1">
     <property name="textAlignment">
      <set>AlignCenter</set>
     </property>
    </item>
   </widget>
   <widget class="QPushButton" name="Button">
    <property name="geometry">
     <rect>
      <x>30</x>
      <y>180</y>
      <width>75</width>
      <height>23</height>
     </rect>
    </property>
    <property name="text">
     <string>PushButton</string>
    </property>
   </widget>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QMenuBar" name="menubar">
   <property name="geometry">
    <rect>
     <x>0</x>
     <y>0</y>
     <width>874</width>
     <height>21</height>
    </rect>
   </property>
  </widget>
  <widget class="QStatusBar" name="statusbar"/>
 </widget>
 <resources/>
 <connections/>
</ui>
```